# Nested JPA query using IN clause

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

So I have the following java classes

```
PLAYLIST
private long playlistid;
private String name;
private String playlistpersistentid;
private String librarypersistentid;

TRACK
private long trackid;
private String trackpersistentid;
private String name;
private String artist;
private String album;
private String genre;
private String librarypersistentid;
```

Which have a many to many relationship, mapping to this lookup table:

```
PLAYLIST_TRACK TABLE
playlist_playlistid
tracks_trackid
```

The query I'm trying to write is

```
"Select * from Track where Trackid in (Select Tracks_trackid from Playlist_Track where Playlist_playlistid = '#WhicheverIdWasEntered')
```

Can someone please help me write the query using JPA?

EDIT: I'm trying to return all tracks that are in a specific playlist based on the playlist id.

Comment: and where are the relationship fields? You know, the @ManyToMany?

Answer (score 1):

```
"Select * from Track where Trackid in (Select Tracks_trackid from Playlist_Track where Playlist_playlistid = '#WhicheverIdWasEntered')"
```

That is not a jpql query that's an SQL query, try this

```
"SELECT t FROM Track t where t.Trackid IN (SELECT pt.Tracks_trackid FROM Playlist_Track pt WHERE pt.Playlist_playlistid = :WhicheverIdWasEntered)"
```

Make sure you use the right entities names in your query.

Comment: could not resolve property: Trackid of: com.itunes.backup.entity.Track [SELECT t FROM com.itunes.backup.entity.Track t where t.Trackid IN (SELECT pt.Tracks_trackid FROM Playlist_Track pt WHERE pt.Playlist_playlistid = :playlistid)]

Comment: Looking at your question the Trackid property of the  com.itunes.backup.entity.Track entity is written in lower case. Look into your Track entity for the trackid attribute and use it in your query as it is. The same for the  Playlist_Track entity